# KineticJS: How can I prevent Image from overlapping the stroke?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have an image which is in a KineticJS layer. When I set a stroke with width > 1 the image will overlap the stroke at some points. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/confile/hUE29/5/) I made:

This image shows the problem:

[image]

My Code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 800,
    height: 900
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    var kimage = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        image: imageObj
    });

    kimage.strokeEnabled(true);
    kimage.stroke("#1788a8");
    kimage.strokeWidth(11);

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(kimage);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
};
imageObj.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/CatBlackHearts.png';
```

**How can I prevent the image overlapping the stroke?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canvas stroke is always drawn half-inside and half-outside its bounding box.

The bounding box is the image size.

Therefore your blue stroke is 11/2 = 6.5 pixels inside your image.

So to have your border fully outside the image, you must draw the border separately from the image.

Comment: How do I draw the border separately from the image?

Comment: (1) Create a group, (2) add a stroked rect in the group that's larger width & height than the image by 11 pixels (3) add your image to the group with x=6.5 and y=6.5.